# cv2.error: opencv(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:bad argument) in function 'resize'

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-resizing

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle

########### PARAMETERS ##############
width = 640
height = 480
threshold = 0.65 # MINIMUM PROBABILITY TO CLASSIFY
cameraNo = 1
#####################################

#### CREATE CAMERA OBJECT
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraNo)
cap.set(3,width)
cap.set(4,height)

#### LOAD THE TRAINNED MODEL
pickle_in = open("model_trained.p","rb")
model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

print(cv2.__version__)
#### PREPORCESSING FUNCTION
def preProcessing(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    img = img/255
    return img

    while True:
        success, imgOriginal = cap.read()
        img = np.asarray(imgOriginal)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(32,32))   <------ ERROR HERE
        img = preProcessing(img)
        cv2.imshow("Processsed Image",img)
        img = img.reshape(1,32,32,1)
        #### PREDICT
        classIndex = int(model.predict_classes(img))
        #print(classIndex)
    predictions = model.predict(img)
    #print(predictions)
    probVal= np.amax(predictions)
    print(classIndex,probVal)

    if probVal> threshold:
        cv2.putText(imgOriginal,str(classIndex) + "   "+str(probVal),
                    (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
                    1,(0,0,255),1)

    cv2.imshow("Original Image",imgOriginal)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

#### ERROR :

> File "E:/DATA_SCIENCE/MY_WORK/test.py", line 32, in
>
> > img = cv2.resize(img,(32,32)) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> > Overload resolution failed:
> >
> > - src data type = 17 is not supported
> > - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: data type 17 means `CV_8SC3`

Comment: You want this structure. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d and your image has the wrong type of data as mentioned above. Set a proper datatype in np.asarray().

Comment: change img type to uint8

Answer (score 0):

You should release your "cap" end of the code below, out of while loop.

```
     if probVal> threshold:
        cv2.putText(imgOriginal,str(classIndex) + "   "+str(probVal),
                    (50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
                    1,(0,0,255),1)

    cv2.imshow("Original Image",imgOriginal)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Set the cameraNo as 0**. It usually occurs because the camera number of your laptop's or PC's default webcam is 0.